# pyflink tableAPI, multiple sources to single processing table sequence

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink

I'm trying to implement a pyflink job (Via Table API) which does some basic processing from multiple sources, after the data from the sources gets converted into a standard format. I'm able to convert the data from each respective source into the required format ('table schema' with specified columns), but not able to set that data to the 'processing table' for further implementation. This is what I'm going for:

> to convert different source schemas into a standard processing table scheme, which can then be windowed, implement a tabling function (for multiple input rows) etc.

[image]

#### EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestion of avoiding possible reserved names. Changed that, as well as including *alias* after udf implementations (to split up row result to column values / names)... Some progress made, the exception that I'm sitting with now is in the 'central merging table' definition (*Standard Table* in the diagram):

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o50.execute.
: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to create a source for reading table 'default_catalog.default_database.process'.

Table options are:

'connector'='print'

...

Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Connector 'print' can only be used as a sink. It cannot be used as a source.
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.enrichNoMatchingConnectorError(FactoryUtil.java:598)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.getDynamicTableFactory(FactoryUtil.java:559)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createTableSource(FactoryUtil.java:144)
```

Can someone point out how the correct table definition should be please, if the table isn't referencing a source like kafka, files or input data (a temporary view table or something I guess? How that table definition / registration would look)

updated code:

```py
import os
import sys
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from pyflink.datastream.stream_execution_environment import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import TableEnvironment, EnvironmentSettings, DataTypes, StreamTableEnvironment
import pandas as pd
from pyflink.table.udf import ScalarFunction, TableFunction, udf, udtf
import json
import numpy as np
from pyflink.common import Row

# ====== source UDFs:
class sourceUdf(ScalarFunction):
    def eval(self, string: str):
        from dateutil import parser
        import json
        input = json.loads(string)
        time = parser.parse(input['timestamp'])
        return Row(input['key'], time, input) 

class source_two_Udf(ScalarFunction):
    def eval(self, string: str):
        # other custom logic to produce row schema of format: [key, timestamp, content]
        return Row(....)

class sinkUdf(ScalarFunction):
    def eval(self, input: Row):
        recordkey, tm, content = input

        import json
        out = {
            'recordKey': recordkey,
            'tm': str(tm),
            'content': content
        }
        return json.dumps(out)

# ======

  env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
  env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib_py/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.12-1.14.0.jar")
  settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance()\
                      .in_streaming_mode()\
                      .use_blink_planner()\
                      .build()

  source_ddl = f"""
            CREATE TABLE source_table(
                entry STRING
            ) WITH (
              'connector' = 'kafka',
              'topic' = '{KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC}',
              'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{','.join(KAFKA_SERVERS)}',
              'properties.group.id' = '{KAFKA_GROUP_ID}',
              'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'PLAIN',
              'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
              'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"{KAFKA_USERNAME}\" password=\"{KAFKA_PASSWORD}\";',
              'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
              'format' = 'raw'
            )
            """

  source_ddl2 = f"""
            CREATE TABLE second_source_table(
                entry STRING
            ) WITH (
              'connector' = 'kafka',
              'topic' = '{KAFKA_SOURCE2_TOPIC}',
              'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{','.join(KAFKA_SERVERS)}',
              'properties.group.id' = '{KAFKA_GROUP_ID}',
              'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'PLAIN',
              'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
              'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"{KAFKA_USERNAME}\" password=\"{KAFKA_PASSWORD}\";',
              'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
              'format' = 'raw'
            )
            """

  sink_ddl = f"""
            CREATE TABLE sink_table(
                entry STRING
            ) WITH (
              'connector' = 'print'
            )
            """

  t_env.execute_sql(source_ddl).wait()
  t_env.execute_sql(source_ddl2).wait()
  t_env.execute_sql(sink_ddl).wait()

  # intermediate table which should receive all the converted source data
  t_env.execute_sql(f"""
        CREATE TABLE process (
            recordKey STRING, 
            tm TIMESTAMP(3), 
            content STRING,
            WATERMARK FOR tm AS tm - INTERVAL '5' SECONDS
        ) WITH ( 
            'connector' = 'print'
        )
    """).wait()

  source_udf = udf(sourceUdf(), result_type=DataTypes.ROW([DataTypes.FIELD('recordKey', DataTypes.STRING()),DataTypes.FIELD('tm',  DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3)), DataTypes.FIELD('content', DataTypes.STRING()) ]))
  t_env.register_function("sourceUdf", source_udf)

  two_udf = udf(source_two_Udf(), result_type=DataTypes.ROW([DataTypes.FIELD('recordKey', DataTypes.STRING()),DataTypes.FIELD('tm',  DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3)), DataTypes.FIELD('content', DataTypes.STRING()) ]))
  t_env.register_function("sourceUdf", source_udf)

  sink_udf = udf(sinkUdf(),
    result_type=DataTypes.STRING())
  t_env.register_function("sinkUdf", sink_udf)

  tbl = t_env.from_path(' source_table') 
  tbl = tbl.map(source_udf).alias('recordKey', 'tm', 'content')
  tbl = tbl.insert_into('process')

  tblsrc = t_env.from_path('second_source_table')
  tblsrc = tblsrc.map(source_udf).alias('recordKey', 'tm', 'content')
  tblsrc = tblsrc.insert_into('process')

  merge = t_env.from_path('process') 
  merge = merge.map(sink_udf).alias('entry')
  merge = merge.insert_into('sink_table')

  t_env.execute("test")
```

Comment: It seems like the issue here is that your field definition timestamp has a name clashing with a reserved word. Perhaps try to backtick the name using  `

Comment: thank you @FrancescoGuardiani. Did what you proposed in avoiding any _reserved words_ altogether. I've updated my question to the current exception, which seems like the 'merging table' registration.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your pipeline is that you're using the table `process` as source table here:

```
merge = t_env.from_path('process')
```

Because `process` uses `connector = 'print'`, you cannot use it as source, as `print` connector works only as sink (insert into).

Looking at your pipeline, it seems like you use the `process` table to merge content from the first and second pipeline, and then push this result in the sink. I suggest you one of the two options:

- You use a connector that can be used both as sink and source, for example [filesystem connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/filesystem/)
- You split the pipeline, and the intermediate table could be a VIEW instead

Comment: As a side note, the flink community is working on improving the experience with these use cases, introducing a built in table storage as shown here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-188%3A+Introduce+Built-in+Dynamic+Table+Storage#FLIP188:IntroduceBuiltinDynamicTableStorage-Example

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @Francesco. Based on my image ('standard table' in the flow diagram), could you please elaborate on which approach you would follow? (I haven't worked with either), and an example to the approach, or link or something?

Comment: It really depends on whether you can have two non converging pipelines or the same pipeline. If after result you need simple maps and filter, then having two pipelines is fine because semantically one pipeline with merged sources or two pipelines have the same meaning. But in your case, it seems like after the process table you have windowing and a multi row function, so you need a single pipeline because splitting the stream have different semantics in regards to these two operations.

Comment: yes, I specifically want to take all the processing from the 2 sources through to the one pipeline. The 2 sources will have different content, but mapped to the same basic schema so that the 'records' can be windowed within a specific time span (thus watermarking required on the timestamp field), to be processed and then merged as a single 'record' further. Currently I made the _standard Table_ as sinks for the 2 sources, and then as a source for the final pipeline.... but I just want a simplistic _in memory_ alternative to temporarily keep the data to be windowed on.

Comment: You can also take a look at the concept of statement sets. They allow multiple sinks that share common sub parts of the pipeline. TableEnvironment.createStatamentSet but not sure if this is exposed in Python.